# Accessing sub-directory file content using showDirectoryPicker()

Tags: javascript, html, file-system-access-api

Using the [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/), how would I access the files contained within a folder of the chosen directory?

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
  for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
    if (entry.kind === "file"){
      const file = await entry.getFile();
      const text = await file.text();
      console.log(text);
    }
    if (entry.kind === "directory"){
      /* for file in this directory do something */ 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Choose Directory</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the [`dirHandle.getDirectoryHandle(name, options)`](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#api-filesystemdirectoryhandle-getdirectoryhandle) method, with the `name` parameter set to your entry's `.name`.

Here is an example code that will walk through a passed directory and build a tree of the files it found.

```
btn.onclick = async (evt) => {
  const out = {};
  const dirHandle = await showDirectoryPicker();  
  await handleDirectoryEntry( dirHandle, out );
  console.log( out );
};
async function handleDirectoryEntry( dirHandle, out ) {
  for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
    if (entry.kind === "file"){
      const file = await entry.getFile();
      out[ file.name ] = file;
    }
    if (entry.kind === "directory") {
      const newHandle = await dirHandle.getDirectoryHandle( entry.name, { create: false } );
      const newOut = out[ entry.name ] = {};
      await handleDirectoryEntry( newHandle, newOut );
    }
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://navigate-sub-directory.glitch.me/), [edit code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/navigate-sub-directory?path=script.js%3A19%3A1).

Answer (score 7):

A small improvement to Kaiido's answer:

```
btn.onclick = async (evt) => {
  const out = {};
  const dirHandle = await showDirectoryPicker();  
  await handleDirectoryEntry( dirHandle, out );
  console.log( out );
};
async function handleDirectoryEntry( dirHandle, out ) {
  for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
    if (entry.kind === "file"){
      const file = await entry.getFile();
      out[ file.name ] = file;
    }
    if (entry.kind === "directory") {
      const newOut = out[ entry.name ] = {};
      await handleDirectoryEntry( entry, newOut );
    }
  }
}
```

`dirHandle.values()` returns a list of objects that inherit from `FileSystemHandle`, there are two possibilities: either `FileSystemFileHandle` or `FileSystemDirectoryHandle`.

Since `const entry` already is a `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` in case when `entry.kind` is `"directory"` there is no need to call  `dirHandle.getDirectoryHandle()`